# Angular UI Typeahead field needs to trigger validation on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous, angular-ui-typeahead

I have an AngularUI Bootstrap Typeahead. It triggers as the model changes to filter the value.

However, I also have a directive attached to this field that should trigger onBlur. The directive searches a database to check if another field is required based on the input of the typeahead field.

If I change ng-model-options to be on blur, I destroy the typeahead. If I change the directive into a function in order to use ng-blur, I can't figure out how to deal with promises and asyncValidators.

Here is my validation directive:

```
 angular.module('myApp').directive('myfieldValidation', ['$q', 'myService', function ($q, myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            ctrl.$asyncValidators.myfieldisvalidated = function (modelValue) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                myService.getdetailsofField(modelValue)
                    .then(function (response) {
                       console.log(response.data);
                       if (response.data.success == false && modelValue !== undefined && modelValue !== "") {
                            scope.launchfunction();
                            defer.reject();
                        }
                        else if (response.data.success == true) {
                            scope.Name = response.data.data["Name"];
                            scope.Number = response.data.data["Number"];
                        }
                        else {
                            defer.resolve();
                        }
                    });
                return defer.promise;
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add timeout to onBlur function.

```
    function onBlurFunction(){
      $timeout(function(){ 
        //some code
      }, 300);
    };
```